# Self complementing Codes

Tags: logic, bcd, digital-logic

This statement was deemed true: **Given any self-complementing decimal code scheme, if we know the codes for the number 283, then we can deduce the codes for 671.**

I wanna know why. I took Excess-3 BCD as the self complementing code:

```
0-0011
1-0100
2-0101
3-0110
4-0111
5-1000
6-1001
7-1010
8-1011
9-1100
```

So 283 = 0101 1011 0110 .

671 = 1001 1010 0011
So why is the statement as it is as 283-ex3 is not a 1s complement of 671-ex3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is self-complementing decimal code scheme, then the code for 9's compliment of 283 can be obtained by taking 1's complement of code for 283.

9's complement of 283 = 716

`283 = 0101 1011 0110`. so its 1's complement = `1010 0100 1001` will be the code for 716.

From this: code for 7 =`1010`, that for 1 =`0100` and for 6 = `1001`

So code for 671 = `1001 1010 0100`